# Two versions of same library linked to target in CMake

Tags: cmake

I'm working on a project that has a setup like so:

```
Project
   '-> CMakeLists.txt
   '-> src
        '-> ModuleA
             '-> CMakeLists.txt
             '-> main.cpp
   '-> thirdparty
        '-> CMakeLists.txt
        '-> protobuf-3.11.3
        '-> Foo
              '-> CMakeLists.txt
              '-> libs
              '-> include
              '-> deps
```

- The protobuf-3.11.3 in thirdparty is compiled each time to a static library and is required by ModuleA.
- 'Foo' is another 3rd party project that only has the include and static libraries already built.
- 'Foo' also contains the transitive dependencies it requires stored in the Foo/deps folder

The CMakeLists.txt in 'Foo' looks like this:

```
 add_library(libfoo STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
 cmake_path( SET FOO_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" )
 cmake_path( APPEND FOO_DIR "include" OUTPUT_VARIABLE FOO_INCLUDE_DIR )
 cmake_path( APPEND FOO_DIR "libs" OUTPUT_VARIABLE FOO_LIBRARY_DIR )
 cmake_path( APPEND FOO_DIR "deps" OUTPUT_VARIABLE FOO_DEPS_DIR )
 
 set_target_properties( libfoo PROPERTIES
                        IMPORTED_LOCATION "${FOO_LIBRARY_DIR}/libfoo.a"
                        INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${FOO_INCLUDE_DIR}"
                        INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "${FOO_DEPS_DIR}/libprotobuf.a")
```

The libprotobuf.a dependency for libfoo was built with protobuf-3.13.0

The CMakeLists.txt for ModuleA looks like this:

```
 add_executable(moduleA main.cpp)
 target_link_libraries(moduleA PRIVATE
                       libfoo
                       libprotobuf)
```

**Question**

The problem I have is this won't compile because ModuleA has a direct dependency on libprotobuf.a which was built with protobuf-3.11.3 and libfoo has a dependency on protobuf-3.13.0. This leads to a lot of multiple definition errors for google::protobuf::<...>
I don't have control over the Foo packages dependency on 3.13.0 or the ModuleA dependency on 3.11.3. Is there a solution to this workaround e.g. having two different version of the same library linked into the main target?

Comment: Perhaps you could write a wrapper lib for `libfoo` that does not require the linking target to deal with anything protobuf related. I know that at least for shared libs you can restrict the exported symbols. If you manage to hide all protobuf related symbols this way you may be able to get away with using different versions of the lib.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't seem to work. I created a new static library (libfoowrapper) that linked with libfoo ```target_link_libraries(libfoowrapper PRIVATE libfoo)``` and then I link against the libfoowrapper target in ModuleA but still the errors about multiple definitions. I really don't get it at all because I thought when specifying link libraries with PRIVATE scope it basically means 'person linking it uses it but not as part of their API so nobody further up the chain should care about it'?